# How to Write a SQL Query to Display list of most used tags in the last 30 days in Wordpress website

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am looking for a way to display the most used tags over the last 30 days on my Baseball blog, built on Wordpress. I am no coder, but I have come up with this mashup to display a list of the most used 28 tags (preference to fit my theme). I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to limit the tags to the most used in the last 30 days.

Here is what I have:

```
<ul id="footer-tags">
<?php
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
   SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = object_id
      WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if(count($term_ids) > 0){

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 28,
    'include' => $term_ids,
  ));
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

The website is slightly less than ~4 weeks old, so to test, I changed `INTERVAL 30 DAY` to `INTERVAL 3 DAY` and the tags being returned seem random and some haven't been used in 2+ weeks and have only been used a single time. As well, only 8 tags are being displayed, when more have been used.

To check that the correct number of days have been queried, I did the following:

Completely deleted all items in the trash for posts and pages, I don't have any custom post types.

Did the same with drafts.

Ran a query in phpmyadmin to delete all post revisions - `DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "revision";`

Ran a query in phpmyadmin to check if the results are the posts from the last 3 days - `SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) <= post_date`

The results from the phpmyadmin query were, in fact, the posts from the last 3 days, but the front-end display did not change.

## UPDATE

Here are some screen shots. Maybe the screenshots can help find where my code is wrong.

**Blog Post with Category and Tags**

[image: Image of blog post]

**`wp_posts` table with the post `ID` of above post**

[image: wp_posts]

**`wp_terms` table with the `term_id` of the tags used**

[image: wp_terms]

**`wp_term_taxonomy` with the tags' `term_id` as `term_taxonomy_id`**

[image: wp_term_taxonomy]

**`wp_term_relationships` with `term_taxonomy_id` assigned to post as `object_id`**

[image: wp_term_relationships]

## UPDATE 2

I think I figured out the problem, but do not know how to fix it.

The SQL query gets the `term_taxonomy_id`, not the actual tag ID and `get_tag_link` uses `term_id`

## UPDATE 3

I have recently created a plugin to display the most popular recently used tags - https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-popular-tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the SQL query code was getting the `term_taxonomy_id`, not the actual tag ID.

I added an additional INNER JOIN using the `term_taxonomy` table to get the `term_id`.  This seems to work, but if a mod can improve this, please do!

```
<ul id="footer-tags">
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?> 
<?php
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if(count($term_ids) > 0){

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 28,
    'include' => $term_ids,
  ));
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

I have recently created a plugin to display the most popular recently used tags - https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-popular-tags/

Answer (score 1):

The PHP variables you are inserting in your SQL string are the *PHP objects* that can be used to access WordPress tables *from within PHP*; whereas you are after the names of the tables and columns for accessing the data *from within SQL*.

You want instead:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships
  INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
  WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= wp_posts.post_date"
```

As an aside: should you ever need to insert the value of a PHP variable into a SQL statement, be very careful to [escape it first in order to prevent any malicious code from being injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: I am getting the exact same results using your solution.

Comment: @TravisPflanz: It sounds as though the initial query is not returning any results (hence the "include" argument to `get_tags` is empty and so all tags are being returned).  I don't know WordPress's schema all that well: are you certain that `wp_term_relationships` joins the `wp_posts` table on the columns you have specified?

Comment: I added some screen shots of the DB tables/fields. If there's something missing, let me know.

Comment: #Update 3#

I think I figured out the problem, but do not know how to fix it.

The SQL query gets the `term_taxonomy_id`, not the actual tag ID and `get_tag_link` uses `term_id`